# how to check if condition for <script> tag?

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a big issue here i have two javascripts.

and i'm testing with a if condition like below:

```html
<script>
if(ie < 9){
 $('#counternew').hide();
 $('#counterold').show();
}
else
{
 $('#counternew').show();
 $('#counterold').hide();
}
});
</script>
<div id="counternew">
    <script src="js/jquery.countdown-new.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
<div id="counterold">
    <script src="js/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

Any how it's not working for me. Can anyone please help me to sort this problem?

Comment: I have the script to find ie9 or not. Now i'm checking the condition if the browser is 'ie 9' use the script jquery.countdown-new.js or else use jquery.countdown.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this syntax

```
<!––[if lt  IE 9]>
<script src="js/jquery.countdown-new.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<![endif]––>
```

For else you can add other if specific